# What do you call the metallic ornaments on an armor?

Tags: word-request

[image]

By metallic ornaments, I mean the ornaments that's part of the helmet on the far left side of the picture. What do you call them?

Comment: I would say Motifs.

Comment: While there may be a technical term used by armor makers in the middle ages, I would doubt there is any general term.  Is the a specific term in your language? Have you checked a bilingual dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am not aware of any word used solely for this purpose, I'd use one of the following words, depending on the context whether you want to describe a single element or a set of them:

- As you have named them, the [**ornaments**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornament_(art)) is a good generic label of decorative elements of art. They might follow a [pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern).
- A [**motif**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motif_(visual_arts)) is a common word used in art and iconography as well.
- A **[pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern)** represents a regular and repetitive arrangement of elements. It might be suitable for most of the armor pieces such as a chain vest is.
- A **[decoration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoration)** is yet another general description of ornaments. This is either used in a lot of museums (see [Metropolitan Museum of Art](https://www.metmuseum.org/toah/hd/decaa/hd_decaa.htm)) as well as [**embellishment**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embellishment).